# Compiler crashes saying a variable from FIR database is unexpectedly nil, millisecs after reading the desired value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here's the function that I call that crashes:

```
func retrieveOtherUserData(){
    profileRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: "aRandomUserID6388").observe(.value, with:{
            snapshot in
            print("snapshot.value is \(snapshot.value!)")
        for item in snapshot.children {

                let profile = Profile(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                otherUID = profile!.userId!
                otherUserName = profile!.firstName!
                otherUserProfilePicURLString = profile!.fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic!
            }
        })

}
```

It consistently says unexpectedly found nil when force unwrapping the profile statements. Here's what profile is referencing:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Profile: NSObject {

var userId: String!
var firstName: String!
var age: Int!
var birthday: String!
var gender: String!
var education: String!
var thisIsMyFun: String!
var iAm: String!
var location: String!
var userLat: Double!
var userLong: Double!
var firStorageNameForFB1: String!
var firStorageNameForFB2: String!
var firStorageNameForFB3: String?
var firStorageNameForFB4: String?
var firStorageNameForFB5: String?
var firStorageNameForFB6: String?
var firStorageNameForFB7: String?
var firStorageNameForFB8: String?
var firStorageNameForFB9: String?
var firStorageNameForFB10: String?
var firStorageNameForPH1: String?
var firStorageNameForPH2: String?
var fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic: String!
var fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic: String!
var fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic: String!
var firDownloadURLForFB1: String!
var firDownloadURLForFB2: String!
var firDownloadURLForFB3: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB4: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB5: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB6: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB7: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB8: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB9: String?
var firDownloadURLForFB10: String?
var firDownloadURLForPH1: String?
var firDownloadURLForPH2: String?
var profileKey: String!
var profileRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

 guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
    guard let userId = dict["uid"] else { return nil }
    guard let firstName  = dict["name"] else { return nil }
    guard let age = dict["age"] else { return nil }
    guard let birthday = dict["birthday"] else { return nil }
    guard let gender = dict["gender"] else { return nil }
    guard let education = dict["education"]  else { return nil }
    guard let thisIsMyFun  = dict["bodyOfThisIsMyFun"]  else { return nil }
    guard let iAm = dict["bodyOfIAM"] else { return nil }
    guard let location = dict["locationOfUser"] else { return nil }
    guard let userLat = dict["latitudeOfUser"] else { return nil }
    guard let userLong = dict["longitudeOfUser"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB1 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto1"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB2  = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto2"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB3 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto3"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB4 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto4"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB5 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto5"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB6 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto6"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB7  = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto7"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB8 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto8"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB9 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto9"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForFB10 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto10"] else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForPH1  = dict["firStorageNameForPHPhoto1"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firStorageNameForPH2 = dict["firStorageNameForPHPhoto2"] else { return nil }
    guard let fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic = dict["URLofSmallFBProfPic"] else { return nil }
    guard let fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic = dict["URLofMediumFBProfPic"] else { return nil }
    guard let fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic = dict["URLofLargeFBProfPic"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB1  = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic1"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB2 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic2"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB3 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic3"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB4 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic4"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB5 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic5"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB6  = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic6"]  else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB7 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic7"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB8 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic8"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB9 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic9"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForFB10 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic10"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForPH1 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForPHPic1"] else { return nil }
    guard let firDownloadURLForPH2 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForPHPic2"] else { return nil }



    self.userId = userId as! String
    self.firstName = firstName as! String
    self.age = age as! Int
    self.birthday = birthday as! String
    self.gender = gender as! String
    self.education = education as! String
    self.thisIsMyFun  = thisIsMyFun as! String
    self.iAm = iAm as! String
    self.location = location as! String
    self.userLat = userLat as! Double
    self.userLong = userLong as! Double
    self.firStorageNameForFB1 = firStorageNameForFB1 as! String
    self.firStorageNameForFB2 = firStorageNameForFB2 as! String
    self.firStorageNameForFB3 = firStorageNameForFB3 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB4 = firStorageNameForFB4 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB5 = firStorageNameForFB5 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB6 = firStorageNameForFB6 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB7 = firStorageNameForFB7 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB8 = firStorageNameForFB8 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB9 = firStorageNameForFB9 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB10 = firStorageNameForFB10 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForPH1 = firStorageNameForPH1 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForPH2 = firStorageNameForPH2 as? String
    self.fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic = fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic as! String
    self.fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic = fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic as! String
    self.fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic = fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic as! String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB1 = firDownloadURLForFB1 as! String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB2 = firDownloadURLForFB2 as! String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB3 = firDownloadURLForFB3 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB4 = firDownloadURLForFB4 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB5 = firDownloadURLForFB5 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB6 = firDownloadURLForFB6 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB7 = firDownloadURLForFB7 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB8 = firDownloadURLForFB8 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB9 = firDownloadURLForFB9 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB10 = firDownloadURLForFB10 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForPH1 = firDownloadURLForPH1 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForPH2 = firDownloadURLForPH2 as? String
}
```

}

For some reason doing virtually the same thing when accessing a specific set of filters worked. Here's the working version of a very similar task and instruction:

```
var filterSet:FilterSet!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    filterSetRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue:   "aRandomUserID6388").observe(.value, with:{snapshot 
        in
            print("snapshot.value is \(snapshot.value!)")
            for item in snapshot.children {

                let filterSet = FilterSet(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                ageRangeFilterDeclined = filterSet!.declinedAgeRange!
                maxAgeMatch = filterSet!.maxAge!
                minAgeMatch = filterSet!.minAge!
                genderPref = filterSet!.genderPreference!
                includeFBFriendsInMatchResults = filterSet!.includeFBFriends!
                includeSportingEvents = filterSet!.sportingEvents!
                includeHiking = filterSet!.hiking!
                includeMiscellaneous = filterSet!.misc!
                includeMuseumsOrArtGalleries = filterSet!.museumsAndArtGalleries!
                includePlayMusic = filterSet!.music!
                includePlaySports = filterSet!.playingSports!
                includeStudyPartner = filterSet!.studyPartner!
                includeDancing = filterSet!.dancing!
                includeTheatre = filterSet!.theatre!
                includeConcerts = filterSet!.concerts!
                includeRunningBuddy = filterSet!.running!
                includeGames = filterSet!.games!
                maxDistanceFilterDeclined = filterSet!.maxDistanceDeclined!
                maxDistance = filterSet!.maximumDistance!
            }
        })
}
```

}

Here's the FilterSet class that gets successfully populated then referenced, unlike what happens with the Profile class:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FilterSet: NSObject{
    var uID: String!
    var declinedAgeRange: Bool!
    var genderPreference: String!
    var includeFBFriends: Bool!
    var sportingEvents: Bool!
    var hiking: Bool!
    var misc: Bool!
    var museumsAndArtGalleries: Bool!
    var music: Bool!
    var playingSports: Bool!
    var running: Bool!
    var studyPartner: Bool!
    var dancing: Bool!
    var theatre: Bool!
    var concerts: Bool!
    var games: Bool!
    var maxDistanceDeclined: Bool!
    var maximumDistance: Int!
    var maxAge: Int!
    var minAge: Int!
    var filterSetKey: String!
    var filterRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else
      { return nil }
    guard let uID  = dict["uid"]  else { return nil }
    guard let declinedAgeRange = dict["DeclinedAgeRangeFilter"] else
      { return nil }
    guard let genderPreference = dict["GenderPreference"] else 
      { return nil }
    guard let includeFBFriends = dict["IncludeFBFriendsInMatches"] else
      { return nil }
    guard let sportingEvents  = dict["IncludeAttendSportingEvent"]  else 
       { return nil }
    guard let hiking = dict["IncludeHikingPartner"] else 
       { return nil }
    guard let misc = dict["IncludeMiscellaneous"] else
       { return nil }
    guard let museumsAndArtGalleries =   
        dict["IncludeMuseumsAndArtGalleries"] else { return nil }
    guard let music = dict["IncludePlayingMusic"] else { return nil }
    guard let playingSports = dict["IncludePlayingSports"] else 
        { return nil }
    guard let running = dict["IncludeRunningBuddy"] else
        { return nil }
    guard let studyPartner = dict["IncludeStudyPartner"] else 
        { return nil }
    guard let dancing = dict["IncludeDancing"] else { return nil }
    guard let concerts = dict["IncludeConcerts"] else { return nil }
    guard let theatre = dict["IncludeTheatre"] else { return nil }
    guard let games = dict["IncludeGames"] else { return nil }
    guard let maxDistanceDeclined  = 
         dict["MaxDistanceFilterDeclined"]  else { return nil }
    guard let maximumDistance = dict["MaxDistanceOfPostings"] else 
        { return nil }
    guard let maxAge = dict["MaximumMatchAge"] else
        { return nil }
    guard let minAge = dict["MinimumMatchAge"] else { return nil }

    self.uID = uID as! String
    self.declinedAgeRange = declinedAgeRange as! Bool
    self.genderPreference = genderPreference as! String
    self.includeFBFriends = includeFBFriends as! Bool
    self.sportingEvents = sportingEvents as! Bool
    self.hiking = hiking as! Bool
    self.misc = misc as! Bool
    self.museumsAndArtGalleries = museumsAndArtGalleries as! Bool
    self.music = music as! Bool
    self.playingSports = playingSports as! Bool
    self.running = running as! Bool
    self.studyPartner = studyPartner as! Bool
    self.dancing = dancing as! Bool
    self.concerts = concerts as! Bool
    self.theatre = theatre as! Bool
    self.games = games as! Bool
    self.maxDistanceDeclined = maxDistanceDeclined as! Bool
    self.maximumDistance = maximumDistance as! Int
    self.maxAge = maxAge as! Int
    self.minAge = minAge as! Int
}
```

}

I also tried to extract the data from FIR Database using:

```
   if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
   otherUserName = dict["userName"], etc.
```

The compiler tells me the desired values are present and readable milliseconds before then crashing upon saying it unexpectedly found a nil value for "profile!userId!" or whichever of the three profile statements I have it read first. (I edit out the extraneous values it also said were in this snapshot):

snapshot.value is {

```
"-Khh__kC9V9mnT1SAbGh" =     {

    URLofMediumFBProfPic = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/10665301_10204284275524944_7824974439027842885_n.jpg?oh=237544b1350b5759e963c2f5b8234f69&oe=594E1F1";
    name = Michael;
    uid = aRandomUserID6388;
};
```

}

I also tried to have these values read after implementing a 3-second delay, but that didn't work.

I don't see any differences between my working code and my non-working code. I am out of ideas for how to solve this problem. Anyone have any idea how my working and non-working examples differ? Sorry for there being so much code above...

Comment: Please format the code correctly, now it is unreadable

Answer (score 1):

changing the profile object to:

```
init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]// else { return nil }
    let userId = dict["uid"] as! String// else { return nil }
    let firstName  = dict["name"] as! String //else { return nil }
    let age = dict["age"] as! Int //else { return nil }
    let birthday = dict["birthday"] as! String //else { return nil }
    let gender = dict["gender"] as! String //else { return nil }
    let education = dict["education"] as! String //else { return nil }
    let thisIsMyFun  = dict["bodyOfThisIsMyFun"] as! String // else { return nil }
    let iAm = dict["bodyOfIAM"] as! String //else { return nil }
    let location = dict["locationOfUser"] as! String //else { return nil }
    let userLat = dict["latitudeOfUser"] as! Double //else { return nil }
    let userLong = dict["longitudeOfUser"] as! Double //else { return nil }
    let firStorageNameForFB1 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto1"]  as! String //else { return nil }
    let firStorageNameForFB2  = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto2"]  as! String //else { return nil }
    self.firStorageNameForFB3 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto3"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB4 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto4"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB5 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto5"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB6 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto6"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB7  = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto7"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB8 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto8"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB9 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto9"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB10 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto10"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForPH1  = dict["firStorageNameForPHPhoto1"] as? String
    self.firStorageNameForPH2 = dict["firStorageNameForPHPhoto2"] as? String
    let fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic = dict["URLofSmallFBProfPic"] as! String//else { return nil }
    let fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic = dict["URLofMediumFBProfPic"] as! String//else { return nil }
    let fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic = dict["URLofLargeFBProfPic"] as! String// else { return nil }
    let firDownloadURLForFB1  = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic1"] as! String// else { return nil }
    let firDownloadURLForFB2 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic2"] as! String// else { return nil }
    self.firDownloadURLForFB3 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic3"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB4 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic4"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB5 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic5"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB6  = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic6"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB7 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic7"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB8 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic8"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB9 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic9"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB10 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForFBPic10"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForPH1 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForPHPic1"] as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForPH2 = dict["firDownloadURLStringForPHPic2"] as? String
    self.activePostID1 = dict["FirstActivePostID"] as? String
    self.activePostID2 = dict["SecondActivePostID"] as? String
    self.activePostID3 = dict["ThirdActivePostID"] as? String
    self.activePostID4 = dict["FourthActivePostID"] as? String
    self.activePostID5  = dict["FifthActivePostID"] as? String
    self.activePostID6 = dict["SixthActivePostID"] as? String

    self.userId = userId as! String
    self.firstName = firstName as! String
    self.age = age as! Int
    self.birthday = birthday as! String
    self.gender = gender as! String
    self.education = education as! String
    self.thisIsMyFun  = thisIsMyFun as! String
    self.iAm = iAm as! String
    self.location = location as! String
    self.userLat = userLat as! Double
    self.userLong = userLong as! Double
    self.firStorageNameForFB1 = firStorageNameForFB1 as! String
    self.firStorageNameForFB2 = firStorageNameForFB2 as! String
    self.firStorageNameForFB3 = firStorageNameForFB3 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB4 = firStorageNameForFB4 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB5 = firStorageNameForFB5 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB6 = firStorageNameForFB6 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB7 = firStorageNameForFB7 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB8 = firStorageNameForFB8 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB9 = firStorageNameForFB9 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForFB10 = firStorageNameForFB10 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForPH1 = firStorageNameForPH1 as? String
    self.firStorageNameForPH2 = firStorageNameForPH2 as? String
    self.fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic = fbDownloadURLForSmallProfPic as! String
    self.fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic = fbDownloadURLForMediumProfPic as! String
    self.fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic = fbDownloadURLForLargeProfPic as! String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB1 = firDownloadURLForFB1 as! String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB2 = firDownloadURLForFB2 as! String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB3 = firDownloadURLForFB3 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB4 = firDownloadURLForFB4 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB5 = firDownloadURLForFB5 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB6 = firDownloadURLForFB6 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB7 = firDownloadURLForFB7 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB8 = firDownloadURLForFB8 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB9 = firDownloadURLForFB9 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForFB10 = firDownloadURLForFB10 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForPH1 = firDownloadURLForPH1 as? String
    self.firDownloadURLForPH2 = firDownloadURLForPH2 as? String
    self.activePostID1 = activePostID1 as? String
    self.activePostID2 = activePostID2 as? String
    self.activePostID3 = activePostID3 as? String
    self.activePostID4 = activePostID4 as? String
    self.activePostID5 = activePostID5 as? String
    self.activePostID6 = activePostID6 as? String
}
```

This results in the original crashing function creating optional values that when forced unwrapped give me the desired values. Not sure why exactly the variables are defined as optional values given that they were defined as non-optional type. Regardless, this somehow solved my problem of not being able to extract needed values.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the init of Profile. You expect optional values (like `firStorageNameForFB3`) but you are using

```
    guard let firStorageNameForFB3 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto3"] else { return nil }
```

So every time `firStorageNameForFB3` is nil; profile will also be nil.

Try change the init of optional values in your model to:

```
    init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
            // ...
            self.firStorageNameForFB3 = dict["firStorageNameForFBPhoto3"] as? String
            // ...
    }
```

and remove the `guard let` for this values.